# How to list all the metadata that is changed after a given date

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, custom-metadata, list-metadata, mdapi

how to get all the metadata changes after a given date.

Tried using metadata api's [listMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm), this gives all the data and here we can't filter using dates. This will run into limits for reports and custom fields.

Is there a way to filter metadata changes by lastmodifieddate, createdbyid ?

Comment: A possible duplicate of [How to query metadata changes in a sandbox based on dates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/how-to-query-metadata-changes-in-a-sandbox-based-on-dates). Look into [RetrieveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieveresult.htm?search_text=retrieveresult)

Comment: I did look into the retrieve result, but retrieve result will fail due to limits for customfields and reports. (System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Exceeded max size limit of 6000000
)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For objects supported by [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling), you can simply write a query for this. Open the Developer Console, click on the Query tab, enter the Tooling API query, and check the "Use Tooling API" checkbox.

## Example

```
SELECT TableEnumOrId, DeveloperName FROM CustomField WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Note: This means you'll have to query all tables you want separately.

Note 2: Not all objects are supported, so if that's the case, you might need to source an alternative method, like querying the [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) and parsing manually. This goes back about six months, though.

Comment: Do we have tables for all metadata types like reports, workflowrules etc ?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to retrieve date information from the Tooling API is quite difficult. The results will vary depending on which call is made and what Metadata Types are supported.

A much easier way is to Retrieve the Metadata in question. Look at the checkRetrieveStatusResponse structure. Under fileProperties you will see createdByName, createdDate, lastModifiedByName and lastModifiedDate. This method returns all of the data information in one API call.

Comment: I want list of metadata that is modified after a given date

Comment: Right. Do a retrieve of the relevant Metadata Types, look through the checkRetrieveStatusResponse structure, and find the dates that are after your given date. Then compile a list of those metadata types. There is no automatic or simple method to get this information.

Comment: I tried that too but for customfields I cannot use it as it gives me limit error 10000 or 39mb

Comment: You are looking at a gigantic org. You can divide the transaction into pieces and everything will work the same way. For Custom Field dates the Tooling API is a better choice. The Metadata API will only give you dates for Custom Objects, but the Tooling API will give you dates for individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single api that provides list of changed metadata components. The best thing we have achieved is to make multiple [listMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm) calls (op alludes to it).

`listMetadata` can take up to 3 types whose components needs to be listed and it returns all components for those types.

For foldered types (Report, Dashboard, EmailTemplate, Document) it is little bit involved. First you need to list all folders using corresponding folder type and then make subsequent calls with combination of folder name and component type (again upto 3 requests per call).

Once you list the components, you can filter out the components locally by comparing the `lastModifiedDate`

We have found that this api has supported any big sized org that we have had to deal with so far to list the components.